# How to parse eve.json output file from logstash using laravel

Tags: laravel, logstash, suricata

I want to parse the eve.json output file of logstash using Laravel. I have tried the JsonMachine package, but I'm getting `Unexpected symbol '{' At position 0.`

Here is a sample output of the eve.json:

```
{"timestamp":2022-04-24T03"}
{"timestamp":2022-04-24T03"}
{"timestamp":2022-04-24T03"}
```

As you can see, this is an invalid json format. That's why the JsonMachine is parsing only the first valid json line, which is the first line. I wanted to parse the whole eve.json file so I can display them on a table using Laravel.

Thank you!

Comment: That looks like corrupt log lines. Are they coming directly from Suricata? Or is Logstash mangling them?

Comment: It's logstash mangling them. I've used suricata for the output of logstash.